# Why does WinSCP prompt for credentials while no FTP servers are active?

Tags: windows, ssh, ftp, sftp, winscp

I have a Windows 10 system running Cerberus FTP Server & CrushFTP. I am actually new to these Two Programs & learning about them for setting up a FTP server at an organisation. I am currently using WinSCP to test connections of FTP, SFTP, FTPS & so on.

The other day I exited these servers & also disabled its services as a part of my testing in emergency cases where they might need to be disabled. I then ran WinSCP just to make sure that they were thoroughly turned off, I actually missed out on the credentials of username & password & clicked on the login just after entering the static IP Address of my System (192.168.1.111) which I normally do but WinSCP yet prompted for a username. I entered the username of a user created on CrushFTP but it didn't prompt for any password. It stated as "connecting to 192.168.1.111" & then "connection failed Timeout detected"

[image]

[image]

So my question is why is WinSCP prompting for username after having no FTP servers running or disabled?? I'm confused a bit!!!!

Sydney

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a way WinSCP is implemented.

As you always need a username for FTP connection, WinSCP will ask you for one upfront, even before trying to connect to the FTP server.

Comment: It could just connect using anonymous though. At least that’s what I’d expect (not having looked at the dialog).

Comment: @DanielB That's just a matter of preference. I would not like my FTP client to assume I want to connect anonymously.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Martin Prikryl. So you mean its just how WinSCP behaves whether a FTP server is installed or not.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've meant.

Comment: Why SFTP dosent behave like that then?? entering a static IP & logging in without a user name & password would just state as ""searching for host" & then connection failed.

Comment: Because there's a very slight possibility that SFTP/SSH server won't ask for username at all. SSH protocol allows that.